# Input and output arguments for ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I am having a problem with formatting my input and output arguments using ctypes in python to access a fortran function in a dll. I can access the library and the function, but am struggling in how to format the arguments.

The f90 code starts as:

```
subroutine DataSub (Data_input,da,db,dy)

    double precision, intent(in) :: Data_input(9)
    double precision, intent(out) :: da,db,dy
```

How do you define the input and output arguments for this case in ctypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from ctypes import *#just for brevity in this example
input = (c_double*9)()
input[0] = .....
da = c_double()
db = c_double()
dy = c_double()
dll.DataSub(byref(input), byref(da), byref(db), byref(dy))
```

Comment: And if one of the outputs was an array, would it be similar? Like if da (in FORTRAN) was length 2 would the call in python be "da = (c_double*2)()"?

Comment: yes chris that's correct. Read the ctypes tutorial, it's very good.

Comment: Yes thanks. I've been reading it but it's vague or confusing in some areas like this. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely these would be c_double, however you shouldn't use "double precision" anymore.
Use real with a kind attribute instead, better yet use the ISO_C_Binding in Fortran to provide a C-like interface.
The ISO_C_Binding would also allow you to pass arguments by value instead of by reference.
Without it you will need to use http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference

Some samples for the ISO_C_Binding are provided by John Reid: http://www.fortran.bcs.org/2002/interop.htm

Comment: ctypes can pass by reference just fine and indeed needs to do so for the out parameters

Comment: Actually, I think without the ISO_C_Binding all parameters have to be byref, regardless of their intent. You also need to be aware of "_" appended by the compiler to the symbols, if not using the binding. Thus, in my opinion, it would be a good idea to introduce some interface definition on the Fortran side. Mimicking the C behavior more closely should allow for better portability and less wonderings on the Python side.